# Alt/Option Drag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Is there a way to simulate a keypress while dragging an element in Capybara? I have a situation where I need to drag while holding down the <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> to simulate a drag + copy operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in Capybara to do what you want - However, depending on exactly which driver you're using it may be possible with driver specific methods.

For instance, if you're using selenium something like the following may work for you

```
#source is the element to drag
#target is the destination element to drop on
page.driver.browser.action.
  move_to(source.native).
  key_down(:alt).
  click_and_hold.
  move_to(target.native).
  release(target.native).
  key_up(:alt).
  perform
```